# How to extract the last 2 delimitered numbers using regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have to extract the first instance of a `number-number`. For example I want to extract `8236497-234783` from the string `bnjdfg/dfg.vom/fdgd3-8236497-234783/dfg8jfg.vofg`. The string has no apparent structure besides the number followed by a dash and followed by a number which is the thing I want to extract.

The thing I want to extract may be at the very start of the string, or the middle, or the end, or maybe the entire string itself is just a `number-number`.

```
$b = "bnjdfg/dfg.vom/fdgd3-8236497-234783/dfg8jfg.vofg";

preg_match('\d-\d', $b, $matches);

echo($matches[0]);
// Expecting to print 8236497-234783
```

Comment: You're missing the delimiter around the regexp.

Comment: @Barmar What do you mean

Comment: Haven't you read the documentation or a tutorial on PHP's preg functions? They explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You're missing the delimiter around the regexp. PHP's `preg` functions require that the regex begin with a punctuation character, and it looks for the matching character at the end of the regexp (because flags can be put after the second delimiter).
2. `\d` just matches a single digit. If you want to match a string of digits, you should write `\d+`.
3. You should require that the numbers be surrounded by word boundaries with `\b`, otherwise it will match the `3` at the end of `fdgd3`

```
preg_match('/\b\d+-\d+\b/', $b, $matches);
```